# Specific search pattern RegExp

Tags: regex

I am new to RegExp, but did some basic tutorial. From the below, I need to be able extract the following. Your help with this would enhance my understanding with RegExp.

Extract String:

```
2016-02-17 19:59:18,182 GMT [transaction-Id=47ad8e96-1db8-4b41-85e5-9256fca485ab] [request_uri=/mydevice/2232234] [] INFO Response:{"executionTimeInMillis":54,"transactionId":"3191569800","success":false,"internalTransactionId":"47ad8e96-1db8-4b41-85e5-9256fca485ab","operationResults":[{"operation":"addDevice","code":"409","message":"Cannot add device"}]}
```

Output string value to be extracted:

1. 47ad8e96-1db8-4b41-85e5-9256fca485ab
2. 22xs32234
3. `{"operation":"addDevice","code":"409","message":"Cannot add device"}`

Answer (score 1):

```
transaction-Id=(.*?)].*?request_uri=(.*?)].*?"operationResults":[(.*?)]
```

extract $0,$1,$2

Answer (score 1):

Perl Code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $string = '2016-02-17 19:59:18,182 GMT [transaction-Id=47ad8e96-1db8-    4b41-85e5-9256fca485ab] [request_uri=/mydevice/2232234] [] INFO Response:{"executionTimeInMillis":54,"transactionId":"3191569800","success":false,"internalTransactionId":"47ad8e96-1db8-4b41-85e5-9256fca485ab","operationResults":[{"operation":"addDevice","code":"409","message":"Cannot add device"}]}';


    if($string =~ /(?:transaction\-Id=)(.*)\] \[(?:request_uri=\/mydevice\/)(.*)\] \[.*(?:operationResults.:\[)(.*)\]\}$/ig){
       print "$1\n$2\n$3\n";
    }
    else{
        print "no match\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=[\/=\[])([^\/=\[]+)(?=\])` if you would like to refer to the match, `(?<=[\/=\[])[^\/=\[]+(?=\])` if you don't.

Is the "22xs32234" expected result is right? Since "2232234" is the original string. If yes, then these expressions are not ready for that yet.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bZ1pK8/1)

Another solution with fewer running step (faster, but figured out it gives back the whole URI which you didn't want):
`(?<=transaction-Id=|request_uri=|operationResults.:\[)[^\]]+`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bZ1pK8/2)

Finally a fixed version of the last one (still faster a bit than first one):
`(?<=transaction-Id=|request_uri=|operationResults.:\[)(?:\/[^\]]+\/)?([^\]]+)`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bZ1pK8/4)